# how to show the omniauth linkedin flash message when user signin with social media account with rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In `devise.en.yml`

```
 omniauth_callbacks:
    failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
    success: "Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account."
```

when I login with social media account it will return the same success message.

please give me any solution for that. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your question in a bit more detailed way? Please paste any examples if you have

Comment: What is the problem? What do you wish to achieve, and what happens instead? Do you see error messages, or are the callbacks not called like you expect? ... ...

Comment: i am using devise for login authentication and omniauth for social media. After login with linkedin it show me flash message like {Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account.} In devise.en.yml i write omniauth_callbacks:
      failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
      success: "Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account."                                          so it give me same flash message written in devise.en.yml. Instead of %{kind} i want social media account name. how it's possible?

Comment: Suppose `auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']` then  `auth["provider"]` will give you the provider name

Comment: refer to this post http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to use `flash[:notice]` directly here. Here device's `set_flash_message` should be used and with that you will need to pass the name of omniauth  `provider` like this:

> set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize)